# Generating hyperlinks to prepopulate Google form

Tags: google-apps-script

**Context:**
I created a Google Sheets/Forms workflow using sequential stages of Google Forms.

1. Form 1 (public facing) Accepts some data submitted by a public user and saves to Sheet 1.
2. Internal staff then contacts the submitter by telephone and conduct a more in-depth interview.
3. Form 2 (internally facing) is used by the interviewer to document
   answers to the phone interview.

This question concerns the generation of Form 2 because I am partially pre-populating it with information from Sheet 1 (Form 1 submissions.) The way I figured out was to formulaically generate a URL with appended pre-population arguments e.g. `"&entry.NNNNNN=whatever"`. I copied-down this formula in the last column of Sheet 1. Clicking on the cell and then the generated hyperlink successfully pre-populates Form 2 with data from the respective row of Sheet 1 as intended.

**Problem:** As soon as a new Form 1 submission is received, a new row is inserted into the Sheet 1 that does NOT contain the desired hyperlink formula in the last column. I would like that to be automatic so the interviewer is not responsible for performing a copy-down before every request for a Form 2.

I have pursued a couple of approaches to automating this:

1. One thread advised instead of copy-down, to create an arrayformula in the top cell so that it applies to the entire column including newly inserted rows as well. I tried every way I could think of but was unable to get my formula to produce a column of results with arrayformula(). If there is a way to fix this, that would be a satisfactory solution.

   > ```
   >    =HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.251357138=",C2,"&entry.966351469=",D2,"&entry.384696201=",E2,"&entry.1366694528=",F2,"&entry.463407115=",M2,"&entry.1557144679=",B2,if(P2,"&entry.1777888516=Email",""),if(O2,"&entry.1777888516=Phone",""),if(H2,"&entry.2110474669=Individual+(Adult)",""),if(I2,"&entry.2110474669=Individual+(Under+18,+Minor)",""),if(J2,"&entry.2110474669=Couple",""),if(K2,"&entry.2110474669=Family",""),if(L2,"&entry.2110474669=Group",""),if(R2,"&entry.1892971721=San+Jose",""),if(S2,"&entry.1892971721=Sunnyvale","")), "Complete Intake")
   > ```
2. I tried to create a ModalDialogue and display a script generated hyperlink in it. I used this approach found in this forum. But this did not open any dialog at all and threw no errors (even after hyperlink was removed.) There was no indication of pop-up blocking. Other parts of my script use Browser.msgBox without any pop-up troubles, but I don't think that will pass a hyperlink.

   > ```
   >  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
   >      .createHtmlOutput('Click to <a href="' + customFillURL + '">open and prefill</a> intake interview form.')
   >      .setWidth(250) //optional
   >      .setHeight(50); //optional
   >  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Ready to fill intake interview form:');
   > ```
3. Using onFormSubmit() and scripting a copydown after a new row has been inserted. But I have been unable to figure out how to identify which row was inserted into Sheet 1. I see some people using lastRow(), but it isn't always inserted into the last row - typically it goes in the middle somewhere.

**Request:**

1. Help getting arrayformula to work in my case.
2. Or help getting ModalDialog to display a script generated hyperlink.
3. Or help on how to identify the row the Form submission inserted. Or do I just need to make sure the table remains sorted by TimeStamp and then I can use lastrow()?
4. Suggestion for a cleaner approach to get to the same place (generating a prepopulated Form from a row of data in Sheet 1.)

Thank you for illuminating a path forward.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using ArrayForumlas to automatically copy down the formula to other rows that have a value in the first column.

Put this formular in row 2 of the column that has the Google Form links.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),
  HYPERLINK(  
  CONCATENATE(
  "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.251357138=",C2:C,"&entry.966351469=",D2:D
)),""))
```

I wrote a [tutorial](https://www.labnol.org/internet/arrayformula-copy-formulas-in-entire-column/29711/) on copying formulas if you need more examples.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I think this is what I tried initially in my approach #1. Unfortunately, in this syntax, the link comes up with the entire column concatenated where a single cell value should be. See the red cells here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qb7mvTTE4-JCHcsnP6ARyTmb0SStESV14hm6yTBSJdQ/edit?usp=sharing
(I changed istext to isblank since my column 1 was a timestamp.)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I was able to successfully employ approach 2, the modalDialog. For some reason no dialog was appearing when I first attempted so I didn't know if there was something fundamental wrong with this approach. I tried again and it worked as shown below so I suppose I just had some typos. Adding `target="_blank"` was helpful so as to open in a new tab.

```
var htmlOutput = HtmlService
      .createHtmlOutput('Click to <a href="' + customFillURL + '" target="_blank">open and prefill</a> intake interview form.')
      .setWidth(250) //optional
      .setHeight(50); //optional
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Ready to fill intake interview form:');
```